Jitsi Meet - how to invite mobile users to access the conferences on my server via app?
I have a server in AWS where I have configured Jitsi for my organization.
The video conferencing system works very well and is already up and running.
I would like to improve it and invite users who use Android or iOS and access via browser to access the conferences using the app.
The app provides some functionality that is not available via the web, such as the ability to share the phone screen.
I have the ability to edit various files, including config.js and interface_config.js
Can you help me to figure out how to do this?
